# GetHostAddress Error (c#)

Tags: c#

So basically, when using this code:

```
    }else if (message.Contains("!resolveip")){
        website = message;
        var ipadd = website.Substring(11).Trim();
        var address = Dns.GetHostAddresses(ipadd)[0];
        string iplel = string.Join("", address);
        SendChatMessage(iplel);

    }
```

In the debug console I receive this: `A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll`

The result is an error in the program, and the ip does not resolve....

Comment: Can you please show what message[0] really contains?

Comment: google.com, it is entered by the user but I am using google.com

Comment: I think you have misspelled the second domain URL? It is identical to the first one.

Comment: This is a simple **debug** problem you can easily solve with a single breakpoint and 1-2 minutes in the debugger - **btw** the problem is most likely in `SendChatMessage` (as you don't use any `Socket`s here) so we **cannot** possible answer this

Comment: Add a debugger and check the run-time value of the variable, `website`.

Comment: @CarstenKönig if there is an error resolving the hostname then a SocketException is thrown.

Comment: @xxMUROxx you are right - sorry!

Comment: @user3124947 you use Substring(11). where !resolveid is only 10 chars long. Fact that Substring starts from 0 you should use Substring(10) to use the correct URL

Comment: @xxMUROxx there is a space between the command !resolveip and the world google.com, anyhow this is not an error (the program compiles and runs and debugs fine), that's what is confusing me

Answer (score 2):

According to your code snippet and its *if clause*, the variables *website* and *message* will contain the substring **"!resolveip"**.

A lookup of a host address for such a string will always fail. The string should be a hostname like "google.com".

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add this piece of code, I'll add it now

Comment: So what can I do to fix it, I ran the code by itself (what you are seeing is set into a bot), and it worked fine. It's really strange..